# How to find query with regular expression that have single quote within / enclosed with single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

as the title, i having problem on finding sentences, or in my case a MySQL query string that have single quotes within an enclosed single quotes words.

For example :

```
UPDATE `blog` SET `BlogDesc` = 'dummy texts' , `BlogHeadlinePic` = 'images12.png' where `BlogId` = 'abcdef';
update `blog` set `BlogDesc` = 'lorem's ipsum' , `BlogHeadlinePic` = 'images.png' where `BlogId` = 'abc'; #need to detect this query
```

so what is the right reguler expression to catch this pattern occured

Comment: Use not direct insertio but prepared stmt.

Comment: i have the query in the .sql file, so not in the application. that's why i need a reguler expression solution for this

Comment: You're asking "how do I write a SQL parser, with regular expressions?". The answer is; you don't.

Comment: @MatBailie i just need to check one case about single quote within / enclosed with single quote. not a whole validation for the SQL query.

Comment: There is  no solution.  Garbage in, garbage out.  Go back to the source of the queries and insist that they properly escape strings.  You should have `'lorem\'s ipsum'`, but there are other viable solutions.

Comment: @NikoliusLau Then you'll falsely identify some, and miss others. Escaping, using " and other features of the language will make this senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^.*'(?:[^'=`;]*'){2}.*;$
```

- `^` the start of a line/string.
- `.*` match zero or more character, note this will match all the string before `'lorem's ipsum'`.
- `'` match a single quote, I will call it quote1, e.g.,  this is the first single quote in `'lorem's ipsum'`, which is before the word `lorem`.
- `` (?:[^'=`;]*'){2} `` non-capturing group. `{2}` means match the whole group two times.

  *First time*:

  - `` [^'=`;]* `` match zero or more characters except `'`, `=`,`` ` `` and `;`, e.g., this will match the word `lorem` in `'lorem's ipsum'`
  - `'` match a single quote. I will call it quote2, e.g., this is the second single quote in `'lorem's ipsum'`, which is after the word `lorem`.

  *Second time*

  - `` [^'=`;]* `` match zero or more characters except `'`, `=`,`` ` `` and `;`, e.g., this will match the string `s ipsum` in `'lorem's ipsum'`.
  - `'` match a single quote. I will call it quote3, e.g., this is the third single quote in `'lorem's ipsum'`, which is after the word `ipsum`.
- `.*` match zero or more character, note this will match all the string after `'lorem's ipsum'`
- `;` ensures that the string in your case the query ends with `;`.
- `$` ensure it is the end of the line/string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcYIhU/1)

**Edit**

If you only want to get things like `'lorem's ipsum'` and not the whole query then just use this regex.

```
'(?:[^'=`;]*'){2}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQFp3Q/1)

Comment: What about `'lorem\'s ipsum'`? That's a perfectly valid string in MySQL. Or `'lorems' ' ' 'ipsum'` which is a legitimate concatenation of three strings?

Comment: @MatBailie This is not mentioned in the OP question.

Comment: @MatBailie SaSky solution is enough for me to check, because the .sql is generated from a user inputed excel file. thanks for the answer SaSky